# Prefix search in a Trie dictionary

Tags: python, search, trie

I have a sample dictionary

```
    {  
   'A':{  
      'P':{  
         'P':{  
            'L':{  
               'I':{  
                  'E':{  
                     'S':{  
                        '*':True
                     }
                  }
               },
               'E':{  
                  'S':{  
                     '*':True
                  },
                  '*':True
               }
            }
         },
         'E':{  
            '*':True
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here `{*:True}` denotes end of the word. I need to find all the possible words I can generate from the dictionary starting with a prefix. For example, the words that I can generate from the above dictionary with the various prefixes are below.

1. 'AP' - > "APPLE", "APPLES" "APE", "APPLIES"
2. 'APP' -> "APPLE", "APPLES", "APPLIES"
3. 'APPLE' -> "APPLE", "APPLES"

I'm basically trying to implement a **Trie** data structure using a dictionary and perform a prefix search.  I think I should implement some recursive algorithm to find all the possible outcomes. I am not able to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: "I'm not getting the proper results" isn't very descriptive. Please show what you've tried and describe exactly how it's failing.

Comment: @glibdud I have tried a few ways. But it was not even close to what I wanted. That's why I didn't post it.

Comment: Unfortunately, as is, it looks like you're just asking someone else to do your work for you. It usually helps to demonstrate that you've put some effort into it on your own.

Comment: Would `'*':False` be possible to appear in the *dict*? If yes what would it mean (what would be the difference between it and `'*':True`)?

Comment: @CristiFati I just added it denote that it is end of the word. If `'*'` is encountered then it is the end of the path.

Comment: Wouldn't then make more sense to have `'S': "*"` or better `'S': None` instead of that `'S': {'*': True}` To mark *S* as the last *char*? Also you still didn't show your attempts to solve the problem ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 2):

i got curious and came up with this recursive variant:

```
tree = {
    "A": {
        "P": {
            "P": {
                "L": {
                    "I": {"E": {"S": {"*": True}}},
                    "E": {"S": {"*": True}, "*": True},
                }
            },
            "E": {"*": True},
        }
    }
}


def descend(node, prefix=""):
    if prefix and prefix[-1] == "*":
        print(prefix[:-1])
        return
    for letter, node in node.items():
        descend(node, prefix + letter)


descend(tree)
```

it prints:

```
APPLIES
APPLES
APPLE
APE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
data = {'A': {'P': {'P': {'L': {'I': {'E': {'S': {'*': True}}}, 'E': {'S': {'*': True}, '*': True}}}, 'E': {'*': True}}}}
def combos(d, c = []):
  for a, b in d.items():
    yield from [''.join(c)] if isinstance(b, bool) else combos(b, c+[a])


print(list(combos(data['A']['P'], ['A', 'P'])))
```

Output:

```
['APPLIES', 'APPLES', 'APPLE', 'APE']
```